# How keep Docker containers running

Tags: docker, fabric8-maven-plugin

I launch integration tests in docker. 
If a test fails then container with tests exits 1 it fails Maven build.
Exactly what I want, but fabric8 plugin removes all containers and I cannot investigate what was wrong. I cannot use docker volumes to put logs there.

I need container keep running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autoRemove` option as the configuration of `docker:start` task.

https://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-configuration

If you set `autoRemove=false` without specifying the restart policy, the container can be kept even after the exit.